# Modified Section Labeling with Theorem Environment

Tags: sectioning, theorems, sections-paragraphs

I am writing up solutions to qualifying exams at my school, and want to label the sections according to the corresponding solutions. The issue, is that each year there are two quals--one in January, one in August. There is an added complexity in that some years, there are also different exams for the Ph.D. and masters program.

Labeling the sections is no issue, I can just write

```
\section{Ph.D. January 2007}
```

The issue, is that I am also using the "theorem" environment, and I want to the theorem environment to reflect these complexities. For example, supposing that my very first section is "Ph.D. August 2004", then I'd like some preamble such that

```
{\section{Ph.D. August 2004}

\begin{problem} Whatever
\end{problem}
```

Would output

```
Ph.D. August 2004


2004.1 (Aug)(Ph.D.): Whatever
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\ExtInf{%
  \StrBetween[1,2]{\sectiontitle}{ }{ }[\pmonth]
  \StrBefore{\sectiontitle}{ }[\ptitle]
  \StrBehind[2]{\sectiontitle}{ }[\pyear]%
}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=\topsep, spacebelow=\topsep,
  headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
  postheadspace=0em,
  headpunct=,
  headformat=\pyear.\NUMBER~(\pmonth)~(\ptitle):~,
]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle,name=]{problem}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{problem}{section}
\pretocmd{\@sect}{\gdef\sectiontitle{#7}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@sect}{\ExtInf}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Ph.D. August 2004}

\begin{problem}
Test problem.
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
Test problem.
\end{problem}

\section{M.Sc. September 2010}

\begin{problem}
Test problem.
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some explanations:

- The [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) packagewas used to capture the title of each section in the macro `\sectiontitle`.
- The [`xstring`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring) package was used to extract from the string stored in `\sectiontitle` the relevant sub-strings; these sub-strings are: the degree, the month, and the year, and they are stored in `\ptitle`, `\pmonth`, and `\pyear`, respectively.

  The macro `\ExtInf` wraps this process, and `etoolbox` is used so that `\ExtInf` is invoked with every new `\section`.

  The title for each section is expected in the form `<degree><space><month><space><year>`
- The [`thmtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtool) package was used as a front-end to `amsthm`; with the help of this package, the theorem-like structure `problem` was defined; using the `headformat` key, the information about the year, number, month and degree are automatically included with the chosen formatting.

### A second simplified version:

This time there's no need to extract substrings; the `\ExtInf` macro receives three mandatory arguments:

```
\ExtInf{<title>}{<month>}{<year>}
```

stores the information in the macros `\ptitle`, `\pmonth`, and `\pyear` and also creates the corresponding `\section` using the macros; then, `thmtools` uses those macros in the `headformat` key to give the desired formatting for the heading of the `problem` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\ExtInf[3]{%
  \gdef\ptitle{#1}
  \gdef\pmonth{#2}
  \gdef\pyear{#3}
  \section{#1~#2~#3}
}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  spaceabove=\topsep, spacebelow=\topsep,
  headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
  bodyfont=\normalfont\itshape,
  postheadspace=0em,
  headpunct=,
  headformat=\pyear.\NUMBER~(\pmonth)~(\ptitle):~,
]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle,name=]{problem}

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{problem}{section}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ExtInf{Ph.D.}{August}{2004}

\begin{problem}
Test problem.
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
Test problem.
\end{problem}

\ExtInf{M.Sc.}{September}{2010}

\begin{problem}
Test problem.
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is absolutely amazing! THank you so much! Is there a way to bold everything though? So, \begin{problem} would also bold 2004.1 etc?

Comment: @AlexYoucis sure; should year, number, month and degree all be bold?

Comment: @Gonzola Medina: Yes, please!

Comment: @AlexYoucis Done! Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Gonzola Medina: I would upvote you to oblivion if I could. One last request, is there any way to make the actual "problem" italicized. So, if I said \begin{problem} Let $u:\C\to\R$ be harmonic. \end{problem} 

that "Let $u:\C\to\R$ be harmonic" is italicized? Thanks again!

Comment: @AlexYoucis Done! Answer once again updated :-)

Comment: @Gonzola Medina: You're a bona fide hero my friend. Thank you :)

Comment: @AlexYoucis You're welcome!

Comment: @AlexYoucis I updated my answer providing a much more simplified version of the code.